# Replace php if else in header of wordpress theme to display both image and text instead of either or

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Right now my wordpress site shows either the logo image or the logo title and logo description. Because the image file renders a very grainy text I want to change the logo image to just display the logo and not the text. Instead I want to add the site logo title and logo description WITH the logo  image. I moved the position of the logo to the left of the logo title and logo description in the CSS. My idea is to render the logo image there using proper php. How can I replace the 'if' 'else' to render both the image and the 'logo title' and 'logo description'?

```
CSS has:
/* Header Top */
#header-top {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 28px 0 0 0;
}
#header-top .header-left a.logo {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
#header-top .header-left a.logo img {
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
#header-top .header-left .logo-title {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial,    sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #000;
}
#header-top .header-left .logo-description {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
} 

php has:
<div class="header-left cf">
                            <a class="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                if ( get_header_image() != NULL ) {
                                    echo '<img src="'. esc_url( get_header_image() ) .'" width="'. get_custom_header()->width .'" height="'. get_custom_header()->height .'" title="'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'" alt="'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'" />';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<div class="logo-title">';
                                    echo get_bloginfo( 'name' );
                                    echo '</div><!--/.logo-title-->';
                                    echo '<div class="logo-description">';
                                    echo get_bloginfo( 'description' );
                                    echo '</div>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </a><!--/a .logo-->
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Umm .... just delete it.  The if line, the else line and the ending `}`, if your not sure then just put  `//` in front of each of those lines and then they are comments and not code.

Comment: I tried that and got a white screen of death :( There is additional code for a cf class... am wondering if that needs to be incorporated. .cf:before,
`code`  .cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}   `code`

Comment: That is another issue, without seeing it, how should I know.  you could turn on error reporting as a first step.  `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` at the top of that page.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
/*  if ( get_header_image() != NULL ) {*/
        echo '<img src="'. esc_url( get_header_image() ) .'" width="'. get_custom_header()->width .'" height="'. get_custom_header()->height .'" title="'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'" alt="'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'" />';
/*   } else {*/
        echo '<div class="logo-title">';
        echo get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        echo '</div><!--/.logo-title-->';
        echo '<div class="logo-description">';
        echo get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        echo '</div>';
/*  }*/
```

I use the block comments in case something is minifing your pages, which would make a mess of things with the `//`

because you are eliminating the check for the image it's best to make sure you have said image, otherwise do this instead.

```
  if ( get_header_image() != NULL ) {
       echo '<img src="'. esc_url( get_header_image() ) .'" width="'. get_custom_header()->width .'" height="'. get_custom_header()->height .'" title="'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'" alt="'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'" />';
        echo '<div class="logo-title">';
        echo get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        echo '</div><!--/.logo-title-->';
        echo '<div class="logo-description">';
        echo get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        echo '</div>';
   } else {
        echo '<div class="logo-title">';
        echo get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        echo '</div><!--/.logo-title-->';
        echo '<div class="logo-description">';
        echo get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        echo '</div>';
  }
```

Add everything in the else to the first block.  Then if you have the image it gets the title information as well.

Comment: Thanks a mill- It's working. I had to make one tweak with the CSS to get the site's logo title and logo description to appear in correct location. I changed the `code`#header-top .header-left .logo-title {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #000; `code` for margin top to read '-85px' instead of  the original '5px'. I appreciate the help. Thanks.